# Move config settings from web.config to ServiceConfiguration.cscfg

Tags: asp.net, c, azure

If I am moving config settings from my Web.config to Aazure ServiceConfiguration.cscfg,
Do I need to make any code changes

For Example my I have the below mentioned entries in my Web.config

`<ConfigurationSettings>
       <Setting name="webConfigHostName" value="Test.AzureTest" />
</ConfigurationSettings>`

To read the above entry,I use

```
string myHostName=MyEnvironmentWrapper.GetConfigurationSettingValue("webConfigHostName");
```

Now I want to move my web application to  Azure Cloud Environment

So I am planning to move the above web.config entries to my *ServiceConfiguration.csfg*
After this do I need to make any code changes so that my application can read "webConfigHostName" directly from  my *ServiceConfiguration.csfg*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm afraid (**in the old days, see below**) you did:

```
if (RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable)
{
    return RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("mySetting");
}
else
{
    return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mySetting"].ToString();
    // or whatever your configuration system requires
}
```

There are some great posts on this [here](http://brentdacodemonkey.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/configuration-in-azure-year-of-azureweek-14/) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/azure/azure-configuration.aspx).

We ended up writing our own wrapper around this to make our application agnostic, so in our code we use a static `Configuration.GetValue()`. A quick global search-and-replace and we were away.

---

**EDIT**: Today this is easier: see the MSDN reference for the [CloudConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt634650.aspx).

Comment: this works great. I've created a project on GitHub which uses a Fluent interface to construct these configuration changes. I will be updating it over time to help with AppSettings as well. https://github.com/SyntaxC4/WindowsAzureConnectionStringResolver

Comment: This is now supported (since June 2012) within Azure SDK: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRARY/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudconfigurationmanager

Comment: Oh lovely! I've amended my answer. Thanks.